# Change profile picture in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a edit profile module , but it needs to change profile picture too.. I already try some code , but the picture isnt change when I press the submit button

Here's the views.py for update_profile

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user )
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():            
            user = user_form.save()            
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user 
            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:                
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']           
            profile.save()         
            return redirect('/profile/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserInfoForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

here's the form

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">                          

                          {% load staticfiles %}
                          {% block body_block %}

                                {% if registered %}
                                  <h1>Update Profile Success!</h1>
                                {% else %}    
                                  <form class="cmxform form-horizontal style-form" id="commentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
                                    {% csrf_token %}        
                                    {{ user_form.as_p }}
                                    {{ profile_form.as_p }}

                                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Update">                          
                                  </form>

                                {% endif %}

                          {% endblock %}                             

                        </form>
```

urls.py (already add +static[]) from someone suggestion and still not working

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', views.update_profile, name='profile'),        
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Hope someone can solve the problem, thank you.

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary information (bunch of url patterns). Note, you have nested forms in your template. However none of them has `action` url defined.

Comment: @IvanStarostin done , but is that necessary? because all the data is updated when i press the submit button , but the probhlem only with the profile picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) in your `HTML` form.

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Your html elements -->
</form>
```

also provide `request.FILES` to your form.

```
profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
```

remove these lines:

```py
if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:                
    profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
```

If you are passing the `request.FILES` to `UserProfileInfoForm` then you don't have to directly assign it to the profile.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the file to your form, so add `request.FILES` as the second parameter to form containing the picture in your view, e.g.

```
profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile
```

Comment: Thankyou it works great , sry for late reply , i dont know what answer to be accepted because both are right.. maybe i will take the longest answer